# Liferay Allow Manual membership option not visible

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2 and I created a organization and site of that organization.
after adding user to the organization.I was editing site configuration, i noticed that my liferay is not showing the "allow manual membership management checkbox".
I am not able to figure out why that option is not visible. i want to enable the manual membership management for organization sites.
Any idea why it's not there?[image]

Comment: Do you have any hooks deployed? You were trying to edit in _Site Administration-->Site Settings_, right? Can you provide the exact steps you followed to reproduce this?

Comment: I have solved the issue with changing the bash files of liferay.When i checked the code of root folder jsp file that code which shows the allow manual membership management was set to hidden.